# Call lightning component from New button on drop-down list of an object tab

Tags: lightning-aura-components, button

I have created a lightning component to override new button on Asset list page. When the new button is used from Asset list page it works as desired, however when I click new from the drop down list it doesn't respond. What am I missing?[image: This New asset should call the lightning component as well]

Steps to reproduce:

- create a lightning component
- override the 'New' button in the buttons available for Asset object with the lightning component
- now the 'New' button is clicked on the list page of the asset, it executes the lightning component I created. (which is expected)

However, I expect it to execute the same lightning component when the New Asset link/button is clicked in the picture. or either there is a different setting which I need to change for the New asset link/button to execute the lightning component(I don't know which setting to change).

I hope my question makes sense, if not please comment what I should provide!

Comment: welcome to sfse, please take some time to read [ask] and take the [tour]. Once you have done so, make sure you include the relevant code (preferable, mnimal reproduceable code sample) and a clear description of the problem alongisde any errors (not working, or not responding is nto usually a problem description) If you are able to provide debug details as well, i will be appreciated. thanks

Comment: I modified the question,  I hope it makes sense now! Thanks for the input :)